# Pattern Matching for List Of List in Scala

Tags: scala

I am getting following for the following `list` in `scala`

```
val x : List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,2,3,4,5), List(6,7,8,9,10))
        x match {
            case x::xs => {
                println ("First  Part => " + x)
                println ("Second Part => " + xs)
            }
        }
```

This outputs following

```
First  Part => List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Second Part => List(List(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Why second part is not only `List(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`, why it is `list of list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the pattern `x :: xs` splits the original input list `List(List(1,2,3,4,5), List(6,7,8,9,10))` in the head and the tail of the list.

The head of a list is the first element in the list. Which is in this case `List(1,2,3,4,5)`.

The tail of a list is the original list, except the first element. So it is a list of all the elements except the first element. In this case, there is only one element after the head, which is `List(6,7,8,9,10)`. The tail is a list which contains this element, so the tail is `List(List(6,7,8,9,10))`.

If you want to match a list with exactly two elements, you can do this:

```
case x1 :: x2 :: Nil => {
    println ("First  Part => " + x1)
    println ("Second Part => " + x2)
}
```

Note that this will only match an input list with exactly two elements.

Answer (score 1):

`case x::xs` is a match for `head::tail`

By definition, head is a single element, whereas tail will be the remainder of the sequence. Since your elements are lists, head is a `List` and tail is still a list of `List` - even though your original list, `x` contains just two elements, so the remaining `tail` is just one element, the type remains.